python: split column value by another column value in dataframe
I have a df:
   string   word
0  anfhfd    f
1  rnvkds    v
2  bkfsgk    k

Code:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( {'string':['anfhfd', 'rnvkds', 'bkfsgk'], 
                'word':['f', 'v', 'k'] } )

I need to split the first word in column 'string', so I tried:
 df[['want', 'notwant']] = df['string'].str.split(df['word'].values[0], n=1, expand=True)

result:
   string  word    want  notwant
0  anfhfd    f      an     hfd
1  rnvkds    v  rnvkds    None
2  bkfsgk    k      bk     sgk

The result above is not what I want. It seems like it splits only 'f' in each row. My expected result is:
   string word    want  notwant
0  anfhfd    f      an     hfd
1  rnvkds    v      rn     kds
2  bkfsgk    k      b     fsgk

Is there any good way to split the word and only keep the column 'want'? I don't need the column 'notwant'

.str.split only seems to accept 1 fixed delimiter and not one per row. You can use .apply with result_type="expand" like this instead:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"string": ["anfhfd", "rnvkds", "bkfsgk"], "word": ["f", "v", "k"]})

df[["want", "notwant"]] = df.apply(
    lambda x: x["string"].split(x["word"], 1), axis=1, result_type="expand"
)

print(df)

Output:
   string word want notwant
0  anfhfd    f   an     hfd
1  rnvkds    v   rn     kds
2  bkfsgk    k    b    fsgk


If you just want the want column:
df["want"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["string"].split(x["word"], 1)[0], axis=1)

print(df)

Output:
   string word want
0  anfhfd    f   an
1  rnvkds    v   rn
2  bkfsgk    k    b

